# Python: BufSize must be an integer

Tags: python, bash

i am trying to run this in my Python Script:

```
for i in array:
    subprocess.Popen("python ~/path/myMrjob.py", "--domain "+i, "~/otherPath/* > ~/otherPath2/"+i+"/output-unsorted.log")
```

I am seeing: `TypeError: bufSize must be an integer`

Answer (score 2):

You should pass a list of the strings you want to be sent to a shell to `Popen` [as the first argument](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen):

```
for i in array:
    subprocess.Popen(["python ~/path/myMrjob.py", "--domain "+i, "~/otherPath/* > ~/otherPath2/"+i+"/output-unsorted.log"])
```

Comment: perfect. could you also tell me how to use wait on this and redirect all output to the shell where i am invoking the script?

Comment: follow up here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28074151/trigger-mrjob-from-python-script-stdout-and-optimal-use-of-wait